# iOS 11 and SSL SNI Support

Tags: ios, ssl, sni

Is there anything special that has to be done to allow SSL SNI to work from iOS?  We have some common code that is using CURL that works on our Android side and not on the iOS Side.  We are getting https error.

```
SSL Connect Error
```

Could not get any more information from the call / get, status is 0, etc.

Is there some special PLIST items that have to be added to support SSL SNI?

---- addition ----

We are using the AWS Cloud Front for this and are looking into the exact versions of all

---- addition -----

verbose output

```
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xx.xx.com (xx.xx.xx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
```

This is common code that Android is using also and is working fine.

we are also setting this for testing

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

Comment: Are you saying that you're using libcurl on iOS (rather than the built-in URLSession?) What code are you using? Are you packaging your own libcurl? Have you set CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION and CURLOPT_VERBOSE to get debug information from curl? What does a network sniffer say you're actually sending? The short answer is "no, there is nothing special you need to do on iOS to use SNI if you use the built-in iOS tools. If you use your own tools, it depends on what tools they are and how you're using them."  Also, why do you believe this is an SNI problem rather than a certificate problem?

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is SNI? There are other ways this error can be caused (cipher mismatch, unsupported TLS protocol version...) and nothing in the information you provide indicates that SNI is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  We have not got to the sniffing, etc and we are going to be doing this.

Comment: We are using common code libcurl and are packaging / creating the request something like. res = curl_easy_perform(curl);  Will try the options and report back